# Probability generating function of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$

Tags: probability, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

Consider $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n,\dots$ as a sequence of independent random variables with probability generating functions $F_1(s),F_2(s),\dots,F_n(s),\dots$. It is well known that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the  probability generating functions of  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is $\prod_{i=1}^{n}F_i(s)$.

Can somebody help me how it works, when we consider $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$? Can I under some condition say that the  probability generating functions of  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$ is $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i(s)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: it boils down to independence justifying the last $=$ in$$E\left[s^{\sum_iX_i}\right]=E\left[\prod_is^{X_i}\right]=\prod_iE\left[s^{X_i}\right].$$

Answer (score 1):

A series of independent r.v 's converges almost surely iff it converges in probability iff it converges in distribution.  If $\sum X_i$ convegence in any of these senses then the generating function of $\sum X_i$ is the product of the generating functions of the $X_i$'s (by DCT).